# Run a Macro without being on the sheet

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am trying to activate a macro while on a different worksheet. I have coded a Macro so that when I select an option from a drop down list it updates a pivot filter field on another sheet. The problem is I have to be on the active sheet for it to work. I have the following code if someone could please help, thanks

```
Sub FilterPageValue()    
   Dim pvFld As PivotField    
   Dim strFilter As String    
   Set pvFld = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Reporting entity")    
   strFilter = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("b2").Value       
   pvFld.CurrentPage = strFilter        
End Sub
```

Comment: Change `Activesheet` to `sheets("sheet name")`

Comment: Hi, tried but It's saying' Subscript out of range, thanks '

Comment: Are you sure you used the correct sheet name when you tried?

Comment: Hi, yes it worked before but had to be on the active sheet, when I try to run it form another I'm getting an error, thanks

Comment: Did you change the "sheet name" in the code to the actual sheet name?

Comment: Hi, yes I changed sheet 1 in the code to the actual name where the drop down list is, thanks

Comment: I meant in this line: `Set pvFld = Sheets("sheet name").PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Reporting entity")`

Comment: Hi , yes just coming up with the error 'Subscript out of range'

Comment: Then either you got the sheet name wrong or, depending on where the code is, you need to specify which workbook too.

Comment: Hi, Def correct sheet name, code was working from the active sheet in the workbook

Comment: Is it the active workbook? If so, use `activeworkbook.sheets("sheet name here")` If you still get the same error, the sheet name is *not* correct.

Comment: Thanks Rory all working now

Answer (score 0):

### Filter Pivot Table Via DropDown

- You have to adjust the name of the worksheet that contains the pivot table (I picked `Sheet2`) in both codes.

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

- This code will run manually.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub FilterPageValue()
   
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Worksheet with cell 'B2'.
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Worksheet with 'PivotTable3'.
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2") ' adjust! this
    
    
    Dim pvFld As PivotField
    Set pvFld = dws.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Reporting entity")
    
    Dim strFilter As String
    strFilter = sws.Range("B2").Value
    
    pvFld.CurrentPage = strFilter

End Sub
```

**Sheet Module `Sheet1`**

- This code will run automatically each time you change the value in cell `B2` of `Sheet1` (dropdown).

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   
    If Not Intersect(Range("B2"), Target) Is Nothing Then
       
        ' Worksheet with 'PivotTable3': adjust!
        Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
        
        Dim pvFld As PivotField
        Set pvFld = dws.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Reporting entity")
        
        Dim strFilter As String
        strFilter = Target.Value
        
        pvFld.CurrentPage = strFilter
    
    End If

End Sub
```

### Follow-Up

- You can rewrite the code as a sub with arguments to easily run the code for multiple pivot tables.

**Sheet Module `Sheet1`**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Range("B2"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Dim pFilter As String: pFilter = Target.Value
        UpdateCurrentPage "Sheet2", "PivotTable3", "Reporting entity", pFilter
        UpdateCurrentPage "Sheet3", "PivotTable3", "Reporting entity", pFilter
    End If
End Sub

Sub UpdateCurrentPage( _
        ByVal WorksheetName As String, _
        ByVal PivotTableName As String, _
        ByVal PivotFieldName As String, _
        ByVal PivotPage As String)
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(WorksheetName)
    Dim pTable As PivotTable: Set pTable = ws.PivotTables(PivotTableName)
    Dim pField As PivotField: Set pField = pTable.PivotFields(PivotFieldName)
    pField.CurrentPage = PivotPage
End Sub
```

Comment: How would add another pivot table to be updated  in another sheet to the code?, thanks

Comment: I've added another version.